# what is [#^String str] in Clojure function type hint

Tags: clojure

I saw a Clojure function like

```
(defn strFun
[#^String str]
(...))
```

I guess the `#^String` is type hint but what is the `#`and `^` before the `String`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the old format for specifying simple metadata tags before it was just `^TagName`. You will see it in code written during this transition from time to time, though there is no need to use it.

```
user> #^String ["hello"]                
["hello"]                               
user> (meta #^String ["hello"])         
{:tag java.lang.String}
```

is the same as not using the `#`

```
user> (meta ^String ["hello"])          
{:tag java.lang.String}                 
user>
```

PS: in this example I tagged a vector with the tag java.lang.String. This point to note is that the symbol you use as a tag will be resolved and the value that symbol resolves to will be used as the tag. So you can't use an undefined symbol.